# Jest not mocking on request-promise-native post method

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am still learning how to make use of jest, but i am confused on why I am facing this issue.

Basically, i want to mock `post` method from `request-promise-native` that is being used in the function i am testing, but for some reason i don't know the spy/mock is not being carried to the declared function and therefore the test fails.

The source file is defined like this:

```
const request = require('request-promise-native')
const recaptcha = {
  endpoint: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
  secretKey: process.env['RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY'] || null
}

class ReCaptcha {
  /**
   * Verifies the captcha token response
   * @param {String} response - The client token response
   * @returns {Promise<Boolean>} - Whether the captcha token is valid
   */
  static async verify (response) {
    const requestOptions = {
      url: recaptcha.endpoint,
      qs: {
        secret: recaptcha.secretKey,
        response
      },
      json: true
    }

    const data = await request.post(requestOptions)

    return data.success
  }
}

module.exports = ReCaptcha
```

The test file is defined like this:

```
const request = require('request-promise-native')
const ReCaptcha = require('./../../../serverless/lib/ReCaptcha')

describe('Lib - ReCaptcha test', () => {

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks()
  })

  it('should request captcha verification', async () => {
    const value = 'foo'
    const expected = true

    jest.spyOn(request, 'post').mockResolvedValue({ success: true })

    const result = await ReCaptcha.verify(value)

    expect(result).toEqual(expected)
    expect(request.mock.calls[0][0]).toHaveProperty('qs.response', value)
  })
})
```

the result of the function is false, and that is due to the response that `request` is getting from google, which makes the mock seem to not be working.

i've debugged the values in the request object when executing the test and i found that `post` method is mocked in the test file, while in the source file it's not.

**NOTE:** I've also tried using `jest.mock` but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can mock `request-promise-native` module and `post` method manually like this:

```js
jest.mock('request-promise-native', () => {
  return {
    post: jest.fn()
  };
});

const request = require('request-promise-native');
const ReCaptcha = require('.');

describe('Lib - ReCaptcha test', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('should request captcha verification', async () => {
    const value = 'foo';
    const expected = true;

    const postSpy = jest.spyOn(request, 'post').mockResolvedValue({ success: true });

    const result = await ReCaptcha.verify(value);

    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
    expect(postSpy).toBeCalledWith({
      url: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
      qs: { secret: null, response: 'foo' },
      json: true
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57416715/index.spec.js
  Lib - ReCaptcha test
    ✓ should request captcha verification (6ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.591s
```